# Variance of the compound sum

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

Trying to solve a Variance evaluation problem:

[image]

Now I'm not sure how to evaluate those two terms on the right hand side of the last equality...
Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, $V(\mu N)=\mu ^2 V(N)$ and $Var (S|N=n) = Var (\sum_{i=1}^N X_i|N=n)\\=Var (\sum_{i=1}^n X_i|N=n)\\=Var (\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)\\=\sum_{i=1}^n Var (X_i)\\=n Var (X_i)\\ =n\sigma^2$.

Last lines are due to i.i.d nature of $X_i$'s.

So, $E(Var (S|N))=E(N\sigma^2)=\sigma^2E(N)$

This is known as Wald equation inliterature.

Comment: Many thanks to A.D and Samrat Mukhopadhyay

Answer (score 1):

$$Var(S)=E(S^2)-(E(S))^2\\ E(S)=E(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i)=E(E(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i|N))=\mu E(N)(\mbox{From independence of $N$ and $X_i$})\\ E(S^2)=E\left(\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N X_iX_j\right)=E\left(E\left(\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N X_iX_j\left|\right.N\right)\right)\\=E(N(\sigma^2+\mu^2)+N(N-1)\mu^2)=E(N)(\sigma^2+\mu^2)+\mu^2(Var(N)+E(N)^2)-E(N))$$ Thus $$Var(S)=\mu^2Var(N)+\sigma^2E(N)$$

Comment: Thank you Samrat for showing me one more approach!